# Parent accounts need to view and pay invoices of child accounts while using SuiteCommerce Premium Customer Center

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

We need parent accounts to have the ability to view and pay invoices on any of their child accounts while using SuiteCommerce Premium Customer Center. It is my understanding that NetSuite doesn't support this. Is there any way that I can accomplish this?

Details: This is the "Consolidated Payments" feature that is used with the Customer Center, but when we upgraded to the Premium account, we lost that ability. We were told by NetSuite that it was a feature of the Premium account, though they offered no explanation. We need this feature.

Comment: What do you mean by account? Do you mean a parent with child subsidiaries?

Comment: Correct. We have parent accounts that represent the company, and then each child account is the individual employee. We want the parent company to have access to the invoices created by their employees.

Comment: Could you be more specific on the record type you're using as parent ? There is no such record type `Company`.  My guess is you may be talking about the `company` field.

Comment: account here in NetSuite term corresponds to Subsidiaries? And you want to view report of all Invoices of a subsidiary and its children subsidiaries?

Comment: I added more information to the post if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you mean by accounts and employee. Within subsidiaries, the parent should be able to see the children's records, thought if you don't, it might be a matter of role permissions.

Try viewing records as `Administrator`. For other roles, you can specify what subsidiary's records can be viewed (own or children).